# Difference between OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder and OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am going through the Google Codelabs Android basics for Kotlin WorkManager.  I've seen the code written one way, then later on see it a different way, and was wondering if there was a difference at all between these?

```
// Add WorkRequest to save the image to the filesystem
val save = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SaveImageToFileWorker::class.java).build()
```

```
// Add WorkRequest to save the image to the filesystem
val save = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SaveImageToFileWorker>()
        .build()
```

Do these do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<T>()` is just a function that creates and returns an object of type `OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder` and there are no differences between them.
You can check the [OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/package-summary#onetimeworkrequestbuilder) function signuature here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It helped clarify for me.